# Запятая перед определением, следующим за глаголом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

*А там ты улыбаешься, ничем не заслоняемая.*

Если определение следует за сказуемым-глаголом, в каких случаях следует ставить запятую? Ведь в следующем примере она не нужна?

*А там ты улыбаешься весёлая.*

Comment: В первом- --- причастный оборот к "ты",  во втором  --- возможно, прилагательное входит в состав сказуемого ИМХО.

Comment: @ВладимирЖеребцов Мне _кажется_, что шапку вопроса необходимо переформулировать: ведь в самом определении нет никакой запятой, она ставится (или не ставится) **перед** определением. Возможно так: _Запятая перед определением, следующим за глаголом_. И добавить метки "запятая" и "определение". Сама не правлю — вдруг станет хуже.

Answer (score 2):

(1) *А тАм ты улыбаешься, **ничем не заслонЯемая**.*

Обособление оборота, пауза, два ударения: на сказуемом (или обстоятельстве) и на обороте.

(2) *А там ты улыбаешься // **весёлая**.*

Определение тесно связано (интонационно)  со сказуемым, нет грамматической паузы, интонация простого предложения (только актуальное членение на тему и рему).

Прочитать его иначе затруднительно, то есть структура предложения задает отсутствие обособления.

**Эта тема рассмотрена у Розенталя** (п.2)  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109

Не обособляются распространенные определения:

**связанные по смыслу** не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым, в состав которого они входят:  *Аккуратный старичок ходил **вооружённый дождевым зонтом*** (М. Г.);  **Обычно** такие конструкции образуются с глаголами движения или состояния, выступающими в роли знаменательной связки.

Если глагол со значением движения или состояния сам по себе служит сказуемым, то определительный оборот **обособляется**: *Трифон Иваныч выиграл у меня два рубля с полтиной и ушёл, **весьма довольный своей победой*** (Т.);

Комментарий

1. Розенталь ориентирует нас на смысловое решение, но оно может быть и чисто **интонационным**, то есть связанным со структурой предложения.
2. При решении этой задачи возможны **разные варианты**, в том числе глагол не обязательно имеет значение движения или состояния, а оборот может быть нераспространенным (одиночное определение), например: *Я пришёл домой **опечаленный**.*
3. В общем случае надо учитывать **различные факторы**: позиция оборота относительно определяемого слова, распространенность оборота, порядок слов. Но в конечном итоге всегда делается проверка с помощью **интонации**.